# VBA how to count rows of filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with counting rows of filtered data. I can manually set the filters and see there are 46 rows but when I use the following code I get 0 rows for results. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
    Dim criteria As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim cr As Double
    Dim crcount As Double
    Dim crtotal As Double
    Dim lastRowInData As Double
    Dim lastRowInFilter As Integer

    counter = 0
    cr = 0
    crtotal = 0
    crcount = 0
    inputWorksheet.Select
    If inputWorksheet.FilterMode Then
        inputWorksheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData 'make sure all data is visible prior to filtering
    End If
    
    'filter the data using the criteria
    With inputWorksheet.Range("A:AB")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=team
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=criteria
        .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="Feature"
        On Error Resume Next
        inputWorksheet.Range("A").Select
        'lastRowInData = inputWorksheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Rows.Count + 2
        'lastRowInData = inputWorksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count + 2
        lastRowInData = inputWorksheet.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        
        
        MsgBox lastRowInData & " rows for " & criteria
        
        If Not lastRowInData = 3 Then
            crtotal = crtotal + inputWorksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count

            'crtotal = crtotal + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(inputWorksheet.Range("I:I"), criteria)
            .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="100"
            .Range("H3").Select
            'lastRowInData = inputWorksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count + 2
            crcount = crcount + inputWorksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
        End If
    End With
    'find the percentage complete and write it to the spreadsheet
    If crtotal > 0 Then
        cr = crcount / crtotal
        cr = Round(cr * 100, 0)
        MsgBox cr & "% Complete " & vbNewLine & crcount & "/" & crtotal
        InfographicData.Cells(row, column).Value = cr & "% Complete " & vbNewLine & crcount & "/" & crtotal
    End If
```

Comment: `On error resume next` hide the possible errors. Temporarily comment out it.

Comment: What do you mean with *"I get 0 rows"*?  Have you checked the content of `crtotal` and `crcount`? Note that you haven't declared those variables and you don't show what you do with them. Also, remove the `Select`-statements, and, more important, the statement `On Error Resume Next` so that you see if an error occurs

Comment: When I say I get 0 rows, I mean I get 0 results from the filtering done by the script. crTotal and crcount were declared as doubles above the snippet I uploaded and they are used to update a cell with the percentage complete. When I comment out the "On Error Resume Next" I get a Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed error which happens on the very next line, inputWorksheet.Range("A").select

Comment: for that `inputWorksheet.Range("A:A").select`

Comment: I updated to include your suggestion Black cat, I was getting and error and commented out the last=RowInData I was using and switched ti the one above it. lastRowInData = inputWorksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count + 2. While I get no errors I still get 0 results instead of the 46 I should get.

Comment: Can you show the content of `team` and `criteria` and what filtering you want to achieve with them?

Comment: Team is being passed in but its GES and criteria is being changed in a loop but looks like (1-a), the 1 changes from 1 - 6 and the a changes from a - e. I am trying to add up the number of features that have completed in a particular capability release (cr).

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern typically works well for determining the number of visible rows in a table of data:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim inputWorksheet As Worksheet, rngTbl As Range
    
    Set inputWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    If inputWorksheet.FilterMode Then
        inputWorksheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    'get a reference to your data table range
    Set rngTbl = inputWorksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'for example
    
    rngTbl.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="blah" 'filter out some rows
    
    'count will include the header row
    Debug.Print rngTbl.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count
    
End Sub
```